# Cut string before one special string and return other

Tags: php, html

Very simple question (i found no similar question).

I have this blow HTML code in string :

```
$one = "<html>
<head>
something>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>";
```

How to return this (From where the `<body>` starts:

```
$two = "<body>
</body>
</html>";
```

I need to find where the `<body>` starts, and then delete everything before that.

How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `strpos()` and `substr()` functions. In my case I used the `mb_` equivalent, because the site may contain non-ASCII characters.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$pos = mb_strpos($one, '<body>');
if ($pos !== false) {
   $two = mb_substr($one,$pos);
}
else  {
   $two = $one;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this, using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$one = "<html>
<head>
something>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>";

$two =  strstr($one, '<body>');
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/173226)

Answer (score 1):

```
$two = substr($one, (strpos($one, '<body>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `strip_tags()` (php builtin) ?

Here's the doc: https://www.php.net/strip_tags